pip install ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))
I try to install packages via python on a Pi within a company network. I use pip version 20.3.4. Other posts mentioned there could be problems v21 upwards, so I did not upgrade.
:~$ pip install --verbose poetry
Using pip 20.3.4 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.9)
User install by explicit request
Created temporary directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-atokuut0
Created temporary directory: /tmp/pip-req-tracker-sr_ghbsb
Initialized build tracking at /tmp/pip-req-tracker-sr_ghbsb
Created build tracker: /tmp/pip-req-tracker-sr_ghbsb
Entered build tracker: /tmp/pip-req-tracker-sr_ghbsb
Created temporary directory: /tmp/pip-install-9x6jlszh
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
2 location(s) to search for versions of poetry:
* https://pypi.org/simple/poetry/
* https://www.piwheels.org/simple/poetry/
Fetching project page and analyzing links: https://pypi.org/simple/poetry/
Getting page https://pypi.org/simple/poetry/
Found index url https://pypi.org/simple
Looking up "https://pypi.org/simple/poetry/" in the cache
Request header has "max_age" as 0, cache bypassed
Starting new HTTPS connection (1): pypi.org:443
Incremented Retry for (url='/simple/poetry/'): Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))': /simple/poetry/
Starting new HTTPS connection (2): pypi.org:443
Incremented Retry for (url='/simple/poetry/'): Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))': /simple/poetry/

I configured the proxy with sudo nano /etc/environment as follows:
export http_proxy="http://gateway.zscloud.net:80/";
export https_proxy="https://gateway.zscloud.net:443/";
export no_proxy="*.network.company; 10.*"

I checked reachability of pypi.org with ping
:~$ ping pypi.org
PING pypi.org (151.101.192.223) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 151.101.192.223 (151.101.192.223): icmp_seq=1 ttl=56 time=18.7 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.192.223 (151.101.192.223): icmp_seq=2 ttl=56 time=18.9 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.192.223 (151.101.192.223): icmp_seq=3 ttl=56 time=18.2 ms

and wget:
:~$ wget pypi.org/simple
URL transformed to HTTPS due to an HSTS policy
--2024-11-26 06:54:36--  https://pypi.org/simple
Resolving gateway.zscloud.net (gateway.zscloud.net)... 165.225.94.44
Connecting to gateway.zscloud.net (gateway.zscloud.net)|165.225.94.44|:80... connected.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://pypi.org/simple/ [following]
--2024-11-26 06:54:36--  https://pypi.org/simple/
Reusing existing connection to pypi.org:443.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 30225902 (29M) [text/html]
Saving to: ‘simple’

simple                        100%[=================================================>]  28.83M  35.6MB/s    in 0.8s

2024-11-26 06:54:37 (35.6 MB/s) - ‘simple’ saved [30225902/30225902]

From these outputs I conclude that the proxy works.
Outside the company network there are no problems. I tested this by connecting to a personal hotspot without any proxies.
I also ensured, that my system clock is synchronized.
Some help is highly appreciated :)
